# Is there a good Arduino enclosure for that works with the Olimex MIDI shield

Tags: arduino-uno, midi, enclosure

I have a MIDI project I put together using an Arduino UNO R3 and the [Olimex Shield-MIDI](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Duino/Shields/SHIELD-MIDI/open-source-hardware).

[image: Omilex Shield MIDI]

I want to install the project permanently in my Guitar rack so I want a decent enclosure, but there doesn't seem to be anything that would support the extra height that the MIDI ports have, relative to the Arduino + Ethernet enclosures.

Has anyone come up with a good solution for Arduino + MIDI projects?  A metal enclosure would be a plus.

Comment: You would need a custom enclosure, or some random enclosure with custom holes. How much do you balance cost against DIY competence? :)

Comment: By Guitar rack, do you mean something like [this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71G5hX2CRKL._SY550_.jpg)?

Answer (score 1):

**Your best bet is to 3D print the enclosure.**

There are many places that will 3D print your enclosure for you and most will mail it to you as well. I would recommend [Shapeways](https://www.shapeways.com/) as they are fairly reasonable in price and ship worldwide.

If you are a handy DIY person you could use [SketchUp](https://www.sketchup.com/) or [Tinkercad](https://www.tinkercad.com/) to design your enclosure. Also there are many Arduino enclosures on [Thingiverse](https://www.thingiverse.com/search/page:1?q=arduino&dwh=475a3e5064c9ae8) that you could use as a starting point.

Alternatively there are often places that will design (and then 3D print) the enclosure for you, you just have to supply your hardware. There are often a few places like this in each city.